How to configure sendmail to forward all mail to another host?
I have an Ubuntu host with a public DNS A record on example.com. The sendmail program is installed on the host with the sendmail package.
The MX records are set up to use Google Workspace,  per Google's instructions. Sending and receiving e-mail through the Web application (GMail) has worked fine since.
However, on the host I also have a Web application server which depends on sendmail to send e-mail, as part of handling Web form submission offered by the site.
To enable sendmail to well, send e-mail, I have followed Google's instructions to enable their MTA relay for use by "scanners, printers and so on", which I assumed was the place to start reading up on how to make it work.
The relay was enabled and I white-listed the IPv4 address of the server so that the host can forward e-mail using presumably device authorization alone (no application passwords or using my personal Google username and password).
I also added, per above instructions again:
define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp-relay.gmail.com')

...to the end of /etc/mail/sendmail.mc, ran make to compile the corresponding /etc/mail/sendmail.cf file [with M4], and restarted the daemon.
It all works for forwarding mail to external domains, i.e. I can sendmail myself@somewherelse.com and it makes it all the way through to my inbox.
Whenever I try to send mail with sendmail myself@example.com, however, that is anything on the same domain as the host with sendmail -- example.com, I think it invariably assumes local MTA (localhost) and doesn't even consider the remote "smart host". This obviously fails unless there's an existing user account with a spool where the mail is stored, as these things go. In any case I don't want the spool to collect mail, so even if I choose to sendmail root@example.com (where root account is assumed to exist on the host) I want it forwarded to remote MTA, so as not to have to worry about matching or mismatching of accounts between the host and Google Workspace user directory.
What is the idiomatic solution to this issue? I can't be the only one with a Web application host that wants to use a remote relay to get e-mail flowing, where the sending host and the e-mail domain name are one and the same. Apparently Ubuntu configures sendmail to only ever consider the local host for MTA for e-mail domain name matching its own. I am no expert on e-mail, certainly not enough to be able to fix this on my own.
What I want is for all mail, regardless of the domain name in the address, to be forwarded for processing to a remote MTA, in this case smtp-relay.gmail.com.
No user+password authentication is supposed to be required according to Google, the sender is simply authorized through the IP address and is cross-referenced using DNS (must match example.com). Like I said, sending e-mail to recipients at arbitrary domains works fine, but not for forwarding (only stored in mail spool for users with an account matching recipient) to recipients at example.com.
I don't want to migrate to Postfix or some such, if the original sendmail can pull this off. I want to understand which part of the configuration is "wrong" in my case.
Posting the /etc/mail/sendmail.mc file below, for posterity. The file contents are as installed by the package manager, with the addition of one single line at the end:
divert(-1)dnl
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# $Sendmail: debproto.mc,v 8.15.2 2020-03-08 00:39:49 cowboy Exp $
#
# Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Richard Nelson.  All Rights Reserved.
#
# cf/debian/sendmail.mc.  Generated from sendmail.mc.in by configure.
#
# sendmail.mc prototype config file for building Sendmail 8.15.2
#
# Note: the .in file supports 8.7.6 - 9.0.0, but the generated
#       file is customized to the version noted above.
#
# This file is used to configure Sendmail for use with Debian systems.
#
# If you modify this file, you will have to regenerate /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
# by running this file through the m4 preprocessor via one of the following:
#       * make   (or make -C /etc/mail)
#       * sendmailconfig
#       * m4 /etc/mail/sendmail.mc > /etc/mail/sendmail.cf
# The first two options are preferred as they will also update other files
# that depend upon the contents of this file.
#
# The best documentation for this .mc file is:
# /usr/share/doc/sendmail-doc/cf.README.gz
#
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
divert(0)dnl
#
#   Copyright (c) 1998-2005 Richard Nelson.  All Rights Reserved.
#
#  This file is used to configure Sendmail for use with Debian systems.
#
define(`_USE_ETC_MAIL_')dnl
include(`/usr/share/sendmail/cf/m4/cf.m4')dnl
VERSIONID(`$Id: sendmail.mc, v 8.15.2-18 2020-03-08 00:39:49 cowboy Exp $')
OSTYPE(`debian')dnl
DOMAIN(`debian-mta')dnl
dnl # Items controlled by /etc/mail/sendmail.conf - DO NOT TOUCH HERE
undefine(`confHOST_STATUS_DIRECTORY')dnl        #DAEMON_HOSTSTATS=
dnl # Items controlled by /etc/mail/sendmail.conf - DO NOT TOUCH HERE
dnl #
dnl # General defines
dnl #
dnl # SAFE_FILE_ENV: [undefined] If set, sendmail will do a chroot()
dnl #   into this directory before writing files.
dnl #   If *all* your user accounts are under /home then use that
dnl #   instead - it will prevent any writes outside of /home !
dnl #   define(`confSAFE_FILE_ENV',             `')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Daemon options - restrict to servicing LOCALHOST ONLY !!!
dnl # Remove `, Addr=' clauses to receive from any interface
dnl # If you want to support IPv6, switch the commented/uncommentd lines
dnl #
FEATURE(`no_default_msa')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MTA-v6, Port=smtp, Addr=::1')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MTA-v4, Port=smtp, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
dnl DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet6, Name=MSP-v6, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=::1')dnl
DAEMON_OPTIONS(`Family=inet,  Name=MSP-v4, Port=submission, M=Ea, Addr=127.0.0.1')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Be somewhat anal in what we allow
define(`confPRIVACY_FLAGS',dnl
`needmailhelo,needexpnhelo,needvrfyhelo,restrictqrun,restrictexpand,nobodyreturn,authwarnings')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Define connection throttling and window length
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_THROTTLE', `15')dnl
define(`confCONNECTION_RATE_WINDOW_SIZE',`10m')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Features
dnl #
dnl # use /etc/mail/local-host-names
FEATURE(`use_cw_file')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The access db is the basis for most of sendmail's checking
FEATURE(`access_db', , `skip')dnl
dnl #
dnl # The greet_pause feature stops some automail bots - but check the
dnl # provided access db for details on excluding localhosts...
FEATURE(`greet_pause', `1000')dnl 1 seconds
dnl #
dnl # Delay_checks allows sender<->recipient checking
FEATURE(`delay_checks', `friend', `n')dnl
dnl #
dnl # If we get too many bad recipients, slow things down...
define(`confBAD_RCPT_THROTTLE',`3')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Stop connections that overflow our concurrent and time connection rates
FEATURE(`conncontrol', `nodelay', `terminate')dnl
FEATURE(`ratecontrol', `nodelay', `terminate')dnl
dnl #
dnl # If you're on a dialup link, you should enable this - so sendmail
dnl # will not bring up the link (it will queue mail for later)
dnl define(`confCON_EXPENSIVE',`True')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Dialup/LAN connection overrides
dnl #
include(`/etc/mail/m4/dialup.m4')dnl
include(`/etc/mail/m4/provider.m4')dnl
dnl #
dnl # Default Mailer setup
MAILER_DEFINITIONS
MAILER(`local')dnl
MAILER(`smtp')dnl
define(`SMART_HOST', `smtp-relay.gmail.com')


First thing I'd suggest: comment out the dialup.m4 line and recompile. That has... side effects.

@tsc_chazz, I commented it out, but the change seems to have no effect on my problem, unfortunately.

To deliver messages to local email domain to another host use/define MAIL_HUB.
See MAIL_HUB mc Macro in The Bat Book.
https://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/doc8.12/cf/m4/masquerading_relaying.html#MAIL_HUB

(This is mostly comment - but space & formatting limited above)
I would STRONGLY suggest you avoid using Sendmail unless you are very familiar with it. It does what it does very well when it is properly setup, but it is not forgiving. It's clear from your question that your experience with IT is limited. Personally I would suggest Postfix.

I have followed Google's instructions to enable their MTA relay for use by "scanners, printers and so on"

Really? Where did you configure the username and password required by Google?
Whichever MTA you choose, if you are unable to resolve issues then please provide the actual configuration (the m4 file you showed us is one of many used by make to generate the sendmail.cf file) and sample log entries illustrating the behaviour.

Google's SMTP relay does not require username and password, but it requires white-listing of the client, by IP address, which I have done.

I'll edit the question to include more detail.
